# groupby column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to groupby columns value in pandas but I'm not getting.

Example:

```
Col1     Col2     Col3
A        1        2
B        5        6
A        3        4 
C        7        8
A        11       12
B        9        10
-----

result needed grouping by Col1

Col1     Col2     Col3  
A        1,3,11   2,4,12
B        5,9      6,10
c        7        8
```

but I getting this ouput

<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000025BEB4D6E50>

I am getting using excel power query with function group by and count all rows, but I can´t get the same with python and pandas. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(
    df
    .groupby('Col1')
    .agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
    .reset_index()
)
```

it outputs

```
  Col1    Col2    Col3
0    A  1,3,11  2,4,12
1    B     5,9    6,10
2    C       7       8
```

Comment: you can use `df.astype(str).groupby('Col1').agg(','.join).reset_index()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Very good I created solution between 0 and 0:

```py
df[df['A'] != 0].groupby((df['A'] == 0).cumsum()).sub()
```

It will group column between 0 and 0 and sum it